# contextlib.closing causes mmap bug

Tags: python, mmap

In the normal code, everything is fine, I can read/and write correctly.

```
for i in range(10):
    sleep(1)

    m = mmap.mmap(-1, 1024, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE, tagname='share_mmap')
    m.seek(0)
    cnt = m.read_byte()

    if cnt == 0:
        print("Load data to memory")
        m.seek(0)
        m.write(b"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")

    else:
        m.seek(0)
        info_str=m.read().translate(None, b'\x00').decode()
        print("The data is in memory: ", info_str)
```

Result:

```
> Load data to memory
> The data is in memory:  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
> The data is in memory:  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

But if I wrap it with `contextlib`, like all the tutorial's code, then I can't read anymore.

```
for i in range(10):
    sleep(1)

    # !!!! LOOK AT HERE !!!! I only changed this line.
    with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(-1, 1024, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE,
                            tagname='share_mmap')) as m:
        m.seek(0)
        cnt = m.read_byte()

        if cnt == 0:
            print("Load data to memory")
            m.seek(0)
            m.write(b"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")

        else:
            m.seek(0)
            info_str=m.read().translate(None, b'\x00').decode()
            print("The data is in memory: ", info_str)
```

Result:

```
> Load data to memory
> Load data to memory
> Load data to memory
```

**Why?**
Also, why does everyone like do it in this way — haven't they encountered this bug?

Answer (score 1):

You're mapping anonymous memory as opposed to a file, so the only thing that's making you get the same mapping each time is the tag name. If you already have a mapping with a given tag name, then `mmap` gives you the same mapping again, but if not, you get a fresh mapping. Your first snippet works because the old mappings are still there (since you never closed them), but in your second snippet, the old mapping is gone before the new one gets created, and since it's anonymous memory, that means the data is gone too.

To fix the problem, either do the mapping outside the loop or map file-backed memory instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it doesn't work with anonymous memory (fileno `-1`) since it *does* with a real file as illustrated below. Not sure if this is a bug, or just an undocumented limitation.

```
import contextlib
import mmap
from time import sleep
import tempfile


with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as mmapfile:
    for i in range(5):
        sleep(1)

        # Works if you use a real file.
        with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(mmapfile.fileno(), 1024, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE,
                                tagname='share_mmap')) as m:
            m.seek(0)
            cnt = m.read_byte()

            if cnt == 0:
                print("Load data to memory")
                m.seek(0)
                m.write(b"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")

            else:
                m.seek(0)
                info_str=m.read().translate(None, b'\x00').decode()
                print("The data is in memory: ", info_str)
```

Output:

```
Load data to memory
The data is in memory:  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
The data is in memory:  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
The data is in memory:  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
The data is in memory:  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: This basically just says "it doesn't work" and doesn't explain why at all.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: I disagree. It explains it's because of using anonymous memory and provides proof by showing it does work with a real file. Obviously it's got something to do with the `mmap` module's implement, but I did not bother reading the source code to figure out why.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: Just guessing, the reason that anonymous memory can't be reused after its `close()` method has been called is because it's impossible to know on a subsequent `mmap` request for it whether it's to reopen the last one or something new  and independent (since they all have the same fileno).